# HTML5 Video bounce when scrolling

Tags: html, html5-video

I've noticed that when I embed a video into a webpage with the `<video>` tag, upon scrolling up and down, the video bounces vertically up and down in the browser.  Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: You need to provide more details - what code are you using, which browser, what's the size of the video, and most importantly, is this more likely a performance issue related to the browser in question?

Comment: regular <video></video>, nothing extravagant as far as code. Im currently testing in safari.

Comment: You just mean the video doesn't scroll as smoothly as the rest of the page? It doesn't misbehave in any other way, i.e. permanently changes its position on the page? I'd say there's nothing you can do about it, it's just a side effect of how the video is displayed in the browser, and it probably also depends on hardware.

Comment: this is definitely weird behavior i wish wasnt there

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. The page is pretty straight forward - HTML. It employs CSS and jQuery to display and manipulate the page. However, when you scroll, the video bounces -- it jumps and bounce back to its supposed position. It goes beyond the pre-defined div container border as it seems to jump out of it. Anyone have any idea on how to prevent this?

Comment: Has anyone been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

With a few list of options on the page, try removing the `background-position: fixed` for the container div and to ancestors.

Comment: Please reserve answers for answers, don't repeat the question. Thanks, and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but try putting a CSS property of `position: absolute;` to it. I am pretty sure it is something to do with the browser not any of your coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an embedded webkit browser, I solved it using `position: absolute;` for the video tag, and by placing the data that needed to scroll, inside a scrollable div.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this with certain videos and have solved it with:

```
video { vertical-align: baseline }
```